# How do I pre-populate a report filter from the URL?

Tags: reporting, opportunity, opportunity-lineitem, urlhacking

I have a very simple report which pulls in opportunity line item data.  The only filter for the report is the opportunity id.

I am trying to pre-populate the report with the opportunity id by going to the following endpoint:

```
https://nax.salesforce.com/00O50000003YTGX?pv0=00650000009edLX
```

However, this fails to bring in the filter criteria. I keep seeing people talk about how this is how you can pre-populate filters, but, I haven't been able to get it to work.

Would anyone be able to point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I forgot to save the report with my filter criteria!  I had previously saved the report, however, once I added the criteria I forgot to save it.  Once I did that I was able to start passing in parameters.